# How to include JS libraries in SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I want to use Underscore.js and Backbone.js in a stand-alone SpiderMonkey scriptfile.  I can find only very simple examples of SpiderMonkey scripts.

How do I include Underscore.js and Backbone.js (and other libraries like jQuery) in a stand-alone SpiderMonkey scriptfile? Can you point me to any other useful resources for writing SpiderMonkey js scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
load ('underscore.js');
```

I found a nice [Intro](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/spidermonkey-introduction/)